# Sonarqube is not registering any c# issues

Tags: .net, sonarqube, code-analysis

Since last Friday (04/01/2016) we are using sonarqube in our company.
Somehow one of our project's issues got all closed (without actually being fixed).
And now the project doesn't get any issues back. we even deleted the project in sonarqube and restarted an analysis, this also gives no issues.

We tried many different things to get the issues back
(even making errors on purpose, but this also doesn't generate any issues in sonarqube)

We are running the newest version of sonarqube (Version 5.4) and we start our analysis from TFS 2015 (using the sonarqube start and end build steps)

Any idea why sonarqube does not reconize any issues in this project? while other projects are working fine?

**update:**

This happend after we enabled Code coverage for this build.but disabling the code coverage does not bring the issues back (not even after deleting the sonarqube project)

**update 2:**

start log

```
2016-04-01T13:52:46.3608006Z Executing the powershell script: D:\TFS\Agents\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\SonarQubePreBuild.ps1 
2016-04-01T13:52:48.8767055Z ##[debug]
2016-04-01T13:52:49.1486023Z SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
2016-04-01T13:52:49.2491975Z Default properties file was not found at D:\TFS\Agents\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
2016-04-01T13:52:49.2491975Z Pre-processing started.
2016-04-01T13:52:49.2501934Z Preparing working directories...
2016-04-01T13:52:49.2501934Z Checking for updates... 
2016-04-01T13:52:49.4643435Z SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild Begin Step 2.0 
2016-04-01T13:52:49.4653311Z 15:52:49.298  Default properties file was not found at D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\.sonarqube\bin\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
2016-04-01T13:52:49.4812668Z 15:52:49.318  Updating build integration targets...
2016-04-01T13:52:49.5728988Z 15:52:49.34  Fetching analysis configuration settings... 
2016-04-01T13:52:50.6017668Z 15:52:50.48  Generating rulesets... 
2016-04-01T13:52:52.4025329Z 15:52:52.298  Provisioning analyzer assemblies... 
2016-04-01T13:52:52.4025329Z 15:52:52.3  Installing required Roslyn analyzers... 
2016-04-01T13:52:52.4035284Z Pre-processing succeeded.
```

end log

```
2016-04-01T13:53:07.9072565Z Executing the powershell script: D:\TFS\Agents\tasks\SonarQubePostTest\1.0.36\SonarQubePostTest.ps1
2016-04-01T13:53:13.0399547Z SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1
2016-04-01T13:53:13.0439418Z Default properties file was not found at D:\TFS\Agents\tasks\SonarQubePreBuild\1.0.34\MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner-1.1\SonarQube.Analysis.xml
2016-04-01T13:53:13.0439418Z Post-processing started.
2016-04-01T13:53:13.2623017Z SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild End Step 2.0
2016-04-01T13:53:13.2632986Z 15:53:13.185  Fetching code coverage report information from TFS...
2016-04-01T13:53:13.2632986Z 15:53:13.188  Attempting to locate a test results (.trx) file...
2016-04-01T13:53:13.2632986Z 15:53:13.188  Located a test results file: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\TestResults\********_DENHELDER     2016-04-01 15_53_04.trx
2016-04-01T13:53:13.3739732Z WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetterTests\******.Tools.UrlNameSetterTests.csproj
2016-04-01T13:53:13.3799577Z WARNING: File is not under the project directory and cannot currently be analysed by SonarQube. File: C:\Users\********\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs, project: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter.csproj
2016-04-01T13:53:13.3849424Z SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS is not configured. Setting it to the default value of -Xmx1024m
2016-04-01T13:53:13.3899308Z Calling the SonarQube Scanner...
2016-04-01T13:53:13.6152663Z D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bin\..
2016-04-01T13:53:13.8206640Z SonarQube Runner 2.4
2016-04-01T13:53:13.8206640Z Java 1.8.0_77 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
2016-04-01T13:53:13.8206640Z Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
2016-04-01T13:53:13.8216606Z SONAR_RUNNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
2016-04-01T13:53:13.8216606Z INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
2016-04-01T13:53:13.8216606Z INFO: Runner configuration file: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\.sonarqube\bin\sonar-runner\bin\..\conf\sonar-runner.properties
2016-04-01T13:53:13.8226578Z INFO: Project configuration file: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\.sonarqube\out\sonar-project.properties
2016-04-01T13:53:13.9243592Z INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
2016-04-01T13:53:13.9243592Z INFO: Work directory: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\.sonarqube\out\.sonar
2016-04-01T13:53:14.0270583Z INFO: SonarQube Server 5.4
2016-04-01T13:53:15.4718195Z 15:53:15.217 INFO  - Load global repositories
2016-04-01T13:53:16.8497760Z 15:53:16.772 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=1551ms
2016-04-01T13:53:16.9504838Z 15:53:16.848 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\********\.sonar\cache
2016-04-01T13:53:17.5657725Z 15:53:17.407 INFO  - Load plugins index
2016-04-01T13:53:17.5666818Z 15:53:17.419 INFO  - Load plugins index (done) | time=12ms
2016-04-01T13:53:19.8280384Z 15:53:19.693 INFO  - Process project properties
2016-04-01T13:53:19.9287435Z 15:53:19.829 INFO  - Load project repositories
2016-04-01T13:53:20.4322672Z 15:53:20.341 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=512ms
2016-04-01T13:53:20.5489246Z 15:53:20.379 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
2016-04-01T13:53:20.5489246Z 15:53:20.447 INFO  - Load quality profiles
2016-04-01T13:53:20.7553157Z 15:53:20.614 INFO  - Load quality profiles (done) | time=167ms
2016-04-01T13:53:20.7563196Z 15:53:20.620 INFO  - Load active rules
2016-04-01T13:53:22.6338067Z 15:53:22.584 INFO  - Load active rules (done) | time=1964ms
2016-04-01T13:53:22.6348044Z 15:53:22.597 WARN  - SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
2016-04-01T13:53:22.6348044Z 15:53:22.597 INFO  - Publish mode
2016-04-01T13:53:22.6348044Z 15:53:22.606 INFO  - -------------  Scan ******.Tools.UrlNameSetterTests
2016-04-01T13:53:22.9419040Z 15:53:22.840 INFO  - Load server rules
2016-04-01T13:53:23.1502914Z 15:53:23.109 INFO  - Load server rules (done) | time=269ms
2016-04-01T13:53:23.2599703Z 15:53:23.202 INFO  - Base dir: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetterTests
2016-04-01T13:53:23.2599703Z 15:53:23.202 INFO  - Working dir: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\******.Tools_******.Tools_2AAE705C-6532-43CC-AE13-50D0CAF50141
2016-04-01T13:53:23.2609672Z 15:53:23.204 INFO  - Test paths: Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs, DealAndOrganisationTests.cs, UrlNameConversionTests.cs
2016-04-01T13:53:23.2609672Z 15:53:23.204 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
2016-04-01T13:53:23.2609672Z 15:53:23.205 INFO  - Index files
2016-04-01T13:53:23.3616718Z 15:53:23.258 INFO  - 3 files indexed
2016-04-01T13:53:23.3626689Z 15:53:23.267 INFO  - Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
2016-04-01T13:53:24.1164564Z 15:53:23.921 INFO  - JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetterTests\target\jacoco.exec
2016-04-01T13:53:24.1174530Z 15:53:23.921 INFO  - JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetterTests\target\jacoco-it.exec
2016-04-01T13:53:24.1184497Z 15:53:23.948 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:24.1184497Z 15:53:23.948 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:24.1184497Z 15:53:23.948 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
2016-04-01T13:53:24.1214418Z 15:53:23.975 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=27ms
2016-04-01T13:53:24.1214418Z 15:53:23.975 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor
2016-04-01T13:53:24.1214418Z 15:53:23.992 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\TestResults\********_DENHELDER     2016-04-01 15_53_04\In\DENHELDER\********_DENHELDER     2016-04-01 15_53_01.coveragexml
2016-04-01T13:53:24.4265478Z 15:53:24.342 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor (done) | time=367ms
2016-04-01T13:53:24.4275513Z 15:53:24.342 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:24.4275513Z 15:53:24.342 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
2016-04-01T13:53:24.4275513Z 15:53:24.342 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:24.4295382Z 15:53:24.342 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5412175Z 15:53:24.423 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=80ms
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5412175Z 15:53:24.423 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5422081Z 15:53:24.423 INFO  - DefaultCpdIndexer is used for cs
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5422081Z 15:53:24.423 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5422081Z 15:53:24.424 INFO  - -------------  Scan ******.Tools.UrlNameSetter
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5432050Z 15:53:24.449 INFO  - Base dir: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5432050Z 15:53:24.449 INFO  - Working dir: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\******.Tools_******.Tools_B15194FA-CD32-45C0-AF33-0159CBB19695
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5432050Z 15:53:24.449 INFO  - Source paths: UrlNameHelper.cs, Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5442026Z 15:53:24.449 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
2016-04-01T13:53:24.5442026Z 15:53:24.449 INFO  - Index files
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6449078Z 15:53:24.495 INFO  - 2 files indexed
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6459034Z 15:53:24.495 INFO  - Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6459034Z 15:53:24.515 INFO  - All FxCop rules are disabled, skipping its execution.
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6459034Z 15:53:24.515 INFO  - JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\target\jacoco.exec
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6469042Z 15:53:24.515 INFO  - JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\target\jacoco-it.exec
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6469042Z 15:53:24.517 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6469042Z 15:53:24.519 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=2ms
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6478973Z 15:53:24.519 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6478973Z 15:53:24.519 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:24.6478973Z 15:53:24.519 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor
2016-04-01T13:53:25.4116570Z 15:53:25.191 INFO  - SonarLint for Visual Studio version 1.10.0.0
2016-04-01T13:53:25.6130664Z 15:53:25.424 INFO  - 0/2 files analyzed, starting to analyze: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs
2016-04-01T13:53:26.5214017Z 15:53:26.447 INFO  - 1/2 files analyzed, starting to analyze: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\UrlNameHelper.cs
2016-04-01T13:53:26.7729445Z 15:53:26.658 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor (done) | time=2139ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.7876203Z 15:53:26.658 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8344834Z 15:53:26.658 INFO  - Parsing the Visual Studio coverage XML report D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\TestResults\********_DENHELDER     2016-04-01 15_53_04\In\DENHELDER\********_DENHELDER     2016-04-01 15_53_01.coveragexml
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8454502Z 15:53:26.670 INFO  - Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpCodeCoverageProvider$CSharpCoverageReportImportSensor (done) | time=12ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8534260Z 15:53:26.670 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8544235Z 15:53:26.670 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8544235Z 15:53:26.670 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8544235Z 15:53:26.670 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8554207Z 15:53:26.678 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=8ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8554207Z 15:53:26.678 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:26.8564173Z 15:53:26.679 INFO  - DefaultCpdIndexer is used for cs
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9591176Z 15:53:26.718 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=40ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9601149Z 15:53:26.719 INFO  - -------------  Scan UrlNameSetter
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9601149Z 15:53:26.732 INFO  - Base dir: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9601149Z 15:53:26.732 INFO  - Working dir: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\.sonarqube\out\.sonar
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9611114Z 15:53:26.732 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9611114Z 15:53:26.746 INFO  - JaCoCoSensor: JaCoCo report not found : D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\target\jacoco.exec
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9611114Z 15:53:26.746 INFO  - JaCoCoItSensor: JaCoCo IT report not found: D:\TFS\Agents\_work\2\s\target\jacoco-it.exec
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9621086Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9621086Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9621086Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9621086Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9631057Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9631057Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9631057Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9641027Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9641027Z 15:53:26.748 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=0ms
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9641027Z 15:53:26.866 INFO  - Analysis report generated in 103ms, dir size=46 KB
2016-04-01T13:53:26.9651084Z 15:53:26.882 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 16ms, zip size=18 KB
2016-04-01T13:53:27.4746044Z 15:53:27.205 INFO  - Analysis report uploaded in 322ms
2016-04-01T13:53:27.4746044Z 15:53:27.206 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonarqube:9000/dashboard/index/******.Tools
2016-04-01T13:53:27.4756021Z 15:53:27.206 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
2016-04-01T13:53:27.4756021Z 15:53:27.206 INFO  - More about the report processing at http://sonarqube:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVPSGZxz3AQs4Fy3Ol1M
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5842827Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5852796Z INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5852796Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5852796Z Total time: 13.674s
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5862785Z Final Memory: 11M/249M
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5862785Z INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5862785Z The SonarQube Scanner has finished
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5872738Z 15:53:27.529  Creating a summary markdown file...
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5872738Z 15:53:27.53  Analysis results: http://sonarqube:9000/dashboard/index/******.Tools
2016-04-01T13:53:27.5872738Z Post-processing succeeded.
2016-04-01T13:53:27.6012315Z The build was not set to fail if the associated quality gate fails.
```

**update 3:**

[Background log](http://pastebin.com/iBQ43tni)

**update 4:**

It looks like its a problem with the c# profiler, we now added some Asp.net mvc projects and get a lot of issues based on the javascript and css profiler, however there are 0 c# issues (which is higly unlikly)

**update 5:**

browsing the logs of the TFS build im seeing that somewhere sonarqube issues are reqonized for c#, but they don't end up in sonarqube itself example:

```
UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\UrlNameHelper.cs(31,13): Warning S1067: Reduce the number of conditional operators (4) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3).
2>UrlNameHelper.cs(31,13): warning S1067: Reduce the number of conditional operators (4) used in the expression (maximum allowed 3). [D:\TFS\Agents\Agent-47\_work\4\s\UrlNameSetter\Dev\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter\******.Tools.UrlNameSetter.csproj]
```

**update 6:**

i found a roslyn json log file (refrenced in the end proces) which also contains the issues that sonarqube should see

[Pastebin to ******.Tools.UrlNameSetter.dll.RoslynCA.json](http://pastebin.com/be9SLadv)

**update 7:**

i jsut completly reinstalled sonarqube, but this had no effect. therefor im starting to think that the issue is beeing caused by the sonarqube runner build in with tfs 2015

**update 8:**

Now i'm defenatly sure its not the sonarqube instalation, i ran a sonarqube run on my dev pc and that did put issues in sonarqube...
The search continues

Comment: You're expecting issues on `UrlNameHelper.cs` right ? Can you attach logs of this analysis' [Background Task](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Background+Tasks) ?

Comment: Thats right. tomorrow when i get back into the office i'll pull them up. thanks in advance

Comment: @n_stan see the new backgorund log in the pastebin link

Comment: did you perhaps install vs 2015 sp2 on the build server ? I have exactly the same issue you have and it started after I updated to sp2.

Comment: I have indeed, we installed an instalation of vs 2015 to enable code coverage on tfs. although i have vs 2015 comunity on my dev machine. and i did get to run a "sucsessfull" run of sonarqube from my dev machine. So i'm going to dive some more into that today

Comment: @fluf We are going to try and revert the vs instalation to update 1

Comment: @EdoPost ok let me know if it worked for you, I'm planning to do the same

Comment: @fluf i will, as soon as i know i'll update you

Comment: @EdoPost It seemed to have worked. Issues are being picked up again I still need to fine tune a couple items since im getting a bunch of warnings now but I believe you can post it as an answer if it worked for you since you did the bulk of the work :) code coverage still doesnt work however

Comment: @fluf its still work in progress... apparently if you use the web installer then it automatically gets the update 2, so we're getting the offline installer now. But I'm glad to hear that its working for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108492/discussion-between-edo-post-and-fluf).

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 changed the issue report format, so we couldn't parse the file. Can you check if this comes up with C# plugin 5.1.

Comment: This same thing is happening to me with VS 2015 update 3, sonar 5.6, and c# plugin 5.3.1

Comment: Oh that's good to know, We'll defer the upgrade for now.

Comment: What is `SonarQubePreBuild.ps1`?

Comment: @Kiquenet I'm not entirely sure (i don't work for the company anymore so i can't check it for you) But as i remember it its a file generated by TFS when you run the SonarQube build step. What it does (again as i remember it) is that it downloads your analysis profile and enables the rules in the compiler so that it will generate the nesearity build warnings that it can pick up afterwards from the output. That way sonarqybe can read its errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @fluf we found out that the install of visual studio 2015 update 2 caused these problems.

What the root issue is here is still unkown, but its working now.

Workaround:
Remove the update 2 installation of visual studio 2015 and replace it with either the update 1 or the one without the updates. 
Both work well enough to preform the builds en generate the code coverage files in TFS.

Comment: v5.1 of the c-sharp plugin has been released im going to see if that addressed the issues. The changelog says that it should have http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/C%23+Plugin

Comment: edo, @darren-steadman "Issues" are working after the update I still need to figure out why my codecoverage is not picking up.

Comment: That's good to hear, besides of the coverage ofcource. do the test run as they should and is code coverage enabled in the tfs build?

Comment: This answer led me to the solution with VS2015 Update 3! My C# scanner was outdated, but updating to version 5.3.2 had VS warnings be analyzed by sonar. Thanks!

Comment: @odalet you're welcome, glad you got things things working again

Answer (score 1):

We encoutered the same problem. Upgrading to sonarqube 5.6 with C# 5.3 plugin did solve our problem.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the Quality Profile for the project has/was changed?

Comment: We only have the default "Sonarway" Quality profiles, and haven't changed any setting. Also all the rules are on the default settings

Comment: Is it possible that you have two SonarQube Scanners configured on TFS? The log shows lines for "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 1.1" as well as "SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.0".