# SonarLint version included with Sonarqube C# plugin

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.4

According to this [site](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) the sonarlint or sonar scanner should be version 2 if you are using the C# plugin 4.5 or higher (i am using v5) 
But when I look at the files included the sonarlint version is v1.10.

Is this correct or is the incorrect version currently bundled with the C# plugin.

My problem is that After I installed VS2015 SP2 on the build server SonarQube stopped logging Issues, and with my debugging this is one of the last items on the list of possible causes.

If I change Build Definition to use MSBuild 12 the issues are logged but not on MSBuild 14. And no issues are logged when I execute the process from Command Prompt using MSBuild 12 or 14. From what I can see all the result files and everything still works they are just not imported into sonarqube.

edit: Relates to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401757/sonarqube-is-not-registering-any-c-sharp-issues) basically I am trying to find the actual problem and solution

Answer (score 1):

The [doc](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild) you point at does not mention SonarLint at all. The v2 (in the compatibility matrix) refers to the version the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild so with Scanner for MSBuild v2 and C# Plugin v5 you're all good. SonarLint is a different thing altogether, you shouldn't care about some of its libraries being embedded in the C# plugin.

Comment: ok, I am using the latest SonarQube scanner and the latest plugin and the latest SonarQube and using VS2015 Sp2 and sonarqube does not register any issues when using MSBuild 14 / Visual Studio Build

Comment: a new update has been released to address the issues I listed above C# plaugin v 5.1