# License validation task failed unexpectedly. The application will be shutdown

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

We are having some issues with installing Visual studio 2015 enterprise update 1
Due to an issues with [SonarQube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401757/sonarqube-is-not-registering-any-c-sharp-issues) we wanted to downgrade to Update 1 (from update 2)

However visual studio won't start anymore. 
The ActivityLog.xml shows the following warning:

```
<entry>
    <record>191</record>
    <time>2016/04/11 08:33:46.581</time>
    <type>Warning</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>License validation task failed unexpectedly. The application will be shutdown.</description>
</entry>
```

We tried repair, and a complete reinstall of the visual studio, but both don't seem to reset the license information.

Is this a known issue for anybody else, and if so what's the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I had a simmilar Issue with VS 2022 Enterprise.

VS was starting but closing without interactive Error Message after few seconds.  In the ActivityLog.xml, I had the same Warning.

I was able to start Blend and Sign in there. After that, VS worked again.