# Sonarqube not registering any c# issues

Tags: .net, sonarqube, code-analysis

Probably similar to [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401757/sonarqube-is-not-registering-any-c-sharp-issues), but since it is already answered for a previous version, I'd open a new question for it.

Despite the fact that I've intentionally put *code smells* into my sources, sonarqube doesn't register any issues. An analysis report is generated (*101 KB*), compressed and uploaded successfully. Execution from scanner side is a success.

### Dev configuration:

- IDE: Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 *v14.0.25425.01* **Update 3**
- Framework: *v4.6.01055*
- Language: *C# 6*

### Build configuration:

- Host: Docker over Debian (*v4.4.0.38*)
- Sonarqube: *v6.1* over PostgreSQL *v9.6.0*
- C# plugin *v5.3.2*
- Scanner: SonarQube Scanner *v2.6.1*
- Engine: mono *v4.6.1.0*, XBuild *v14.0*
- CLR: *v4.0.30319.42000*

### Sonar-scanner result:

```
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /opt/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: /builds/kataik/gitlab_test/sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 2.6.1
INFO: Java 1.8.0_92 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.4.0-38-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /opt/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load global repositories
INFO: Load global repositories (done) | time=309ms
INFO: User cache: /opt/sonar-scanner-2.6.1/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=16ms
INFO: Download sonar-csharp-plugin-5.3.2.jar
INFO: Download sonar-java-plugin-4.2.jar
INFO: Download sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar
INFO: Download sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3.jar
INFO: Download sonar-javascript-plugin-2.17.0.3154.jar
INFO: SonarQube server 6.1
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=627ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=332ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=1492ms
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: -------------  Scan Gitlab Test Project
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=155ms
INFO: Base dir: /builds/kataik/gitlab_test
INFO: Working dir: /builds/kataik/gitlab_test/.sonar
INFO: Source paths: src
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
INFO: Index files
INFO: Excluded sources: 
INFO:   **/T_GitLabCi/packages/**
INFO:   **/T_GitLabCi/TestWeb/Scripts/**
INFO:   **/T_GitLabCi/TestWeb/Content/**
INFO: 25 files indexed
INFO: 256 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor
INFO: Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=43ms
INFO: Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor
INFO: Parsing the NUnit Test Results file /builds/kataik/gitlab_test/././test/TestResult.xml
INFO: Sensor org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpUnitTestResultsProvider$CSharpUnitTestResultsImportSensor (done) | time=93ms
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor
INFO: Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=20ms
INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor
INFO: Sensor XmlFileSensor (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=31ms
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor
INFO: Sensor Code Colorizer Sensor (done) | time=178ms
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer
INFO: DefaultCpdBlockIndexer is used for cs
INFO: Sensor CPD Block Indexer (done) | time=226ms
INFO: Calculating CPD for 22 files
INFO: CPD calculation finished
INFO: Analysis report generated in 232ms, dir size=101 KB
INFO: Analysis reports compressed in 117ms, zip size=57 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 145ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://norcaart.com:9000/dashboard/index/my:gilab-test
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://norcaart.com:9000/api/ce/task?id=AVfIFT0XoCxsyitLE2_G
INFO: Task total time: 6.697 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 12.802s
INFO: Final Memory: 45M/125M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### Edit #1: sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.host.url=http://norcaart.com:9000
useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.projectKey=my:gilab-test
sonar.projectName=Gitlab Test Project
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/T_GitLabCi/packages/**, **/T_GitLabCi/TestWeb/Scripts/**, **/T_GitLabCi/TestWeb/Content/**

sonar.cs.nunit.reportsPaths=./test/TestResult.xml
sonar.cs.msbuild.testProjectPattern=*Tests;*UnitTests
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file="./src/T_GitLabCi/T_GitLabCi.sln"
```

Comment: What's the name of your solution/projects? By default analysis on test projects are turned off. Test projects are identified by name, using the `sonar.cs.msbuild.testProjectPattern` property, whose default value is `[^\\]*test[^\\]*$`.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam Hi, I've edited the question, it now has the content of the project properties file.

Comment: Is there any MsBuild project in your solution whose name doesn't contain "test"?

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam yes, I have three which doesn't match the pattern

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I asked "project name", but we're actually checking the project file paths.

Comment: @Tamas-SonarSourceTeam You've been right, thanks. The problem was that all projects which name contained 'test' have been excluded. If you could add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default analysis on test projects are turned off. Test projects are identified by name, using the `sonar.cs.msbuild.testProjectPattern` property, whose default value is `[^\\]*test[^\\]*$`.

Comment: Looking at the default regular expression I can see that 'test' is case sensitive. I have a project which both it's Name and the File Paths contains the word "UnitTesting". This project is not getting analyzed. I can see the files and it's content in SonarQube UI but both lines of code and bugs/vulnerabilities/code smells is 0 (zero). Is Sonar using case insensitive somehow? Just want to make sure my project is getting excluded for the right reasons. Thnx.

Comment: Test projects and excluded files are different. Test projects are not analyzed, but they are uploaded to the SQ server. Excluded projects and files are not even uploaded. You can exclude artifacts like this: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Excluding+Artifacts+from+the+Analysis

Comment: BTW file names in Windows are case-insensitive. We most probably lower case it somewhere before applying the regex.

Comment: @Tamas I have same issue, if I have projectA and projectA.UnitTests, if I both inlude in sonarqube scanner, code coverage does not run, if I only include projectA.UnitTests then, it shows coverage but not code smells. How can I make sonarqube to show both code coverage and code smells?

Comment: OMG this was driving me crazy for hours. Thank you! +1