# Why the SonarQube 8.3 does not check C# code?

Tags: c#, testing, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I am new to SonarQube and its configuration. My post is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058704/sonarqube-not-registering-any-c-sharp-issues), but it is an old one and as I understand several things inside the solution has changed. English is not my native language, please be patient.

I got an SonarQube 8.3 up and running with C# plugin 8.6.1,
[image]

and a SonarScanner 4.3 running aswell for MSBuild for .Net Framework 4.6+. I did not edit the ..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties file,

```
PS C:\test-demo> sonar-scanner
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Sonar-Scanner-MSBuild\sonar-scanner-4.3.0.2102\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
```

I got a test demo in this directory:

```
C:\test-demo
```

That directory have these files

[image]

This is the sonar-project.properties file connfiguration,

```
# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=QRDemo
# this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=QRDemo
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
 
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace "\" by "/" on Windows.
# This property is optional if sonar.modules is set. 
sonar.sources=.
 
# Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.msbuild.testProjectPattern=*Tests;*UnitTests;*Demo
sonar.dotnet.visualstudio.solution.file="C:\\test-demo\\QrDemo.sln"
```

This is the code I want to test, SonarQube should find the errors,

```
using QRCoder;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace QrDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 0;

            string token = "Esto lo vamos a volver qr";
            QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
            QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(token, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            QRCode qrCode = new QRCode(qrCodeData);
            System.Drawing.Bitmap qrCodeImage = qrCode.GetGraphic(10);

            //Opcion A: Desde el memoryStream puedo retornar la imagen sin necesidad de crear fisicamente
            //using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            //{
            //    qrCodeImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            //}

            //Opción B: Se guarda un QR Fisico
            qrCodeImage.Save("imagen.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I run the Scanner I got this,

```
PS C:\test-demo> sonar-scanner
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Sonar-Scanner-MSBuild\sonar-scanner-4.3.0.2102\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\test-demo\sonar-project.properties
INFO: SonarScanner 4.3.0.2102
INFO: Java 11.0.6 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 10 10.0 amd64
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\hpayares\.sonar\cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\Sonar-Scanner-MSBuild\sonar-scanner-4.3.0.2102\bin\..\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\test-demo\sonar-project.properties
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 8.3.1
INFO: Default locale: "es_CO", source code encoding: "windows-1252" (analysis is platform dependent)
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=61ms
INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AXK_1XzT0nTmQjkDht7H
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\hpayares\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=51ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=144ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=17ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=5ms
INFO: Project key: QRDemo
INFO: Base dir: C:\test-demo
INFO: Working dir: C:\test-demo\.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'QRDemo'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'QRDemo' (done) | time=19ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=85ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=1196ms
WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. Please use "sonar.scm.provider" to define SCM of your project, or disable the SCM Sensor in the project settings.
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO: 19 files indexed
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module QRDemo
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=31ms
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/C:/Users/hpayares/.sonar/cache/54f6535c111cefad0fb6a09ba3e61922/sonar-javascript-plugin.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily]
INFO: No CSS, PHP, HTML or VueJS files are found in the project. CSS analysis is skipped.
INFO: Sensor SonarCSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
WARN: Property missing: 'sonar.cs.analyzer.projectOutPaths'. No protobuf files will be loaded for this project.
WARN: No Roslyn issues report found for this project.
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=16ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=0ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
INFO: SCM Publisher No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 0 files
INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=0ms
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=31ms
INFO: Analysis report generated in 157ms, dir size=80 KB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 47ms, zip size=12 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 31ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=QRDemo
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://localhost:9000/api/ce/task?id=AXLeZwScZSZ5s3S2FZtb
INFO: Analysis total time: 12.890 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 14.453s
INFO: Final Memory: 6M/30M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image]

I followed the official guide and watched others guides to no avail , I don't know what I am doing wrong here, ¿Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Scanner for MSBuild to analyze .NET project. Please follow [SonarScanner for MSBuild](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/) documentation page.

Comment: Could you please add more information regarding to the solution? The documentation is not enough. The page is designed for Windows and doesn't has enough information for Linux users. SonarQube.Analysis.xml path is wrong. Also "project key" is not defined clearly; it's a blur field in documentation. How can a working project token be gotten? The project token which is produced in User>>My Account>>Security doesn't work as documented. The token cannot be used as it cannot access to the license information of Sonarqube.